# fill a UIStackView programmatically

Tags: swift3, uibutton, uistackview

I have designed a UIStackView in a StoryBoard and I have added 2 UIbutton with a height contraint set at 70.
My stackview is set to vertical fill and has some constraints set on the storyboard to fit in the Controller's View.

I have added an outlet from the stackView and from the UIbutton.
I am trying to add a third UIButton programatically in the stack View

```
@IBOutlet weak var Btn1: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var myStackView: UIStackView!

var accounts = [Account]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Btn1.setTitle("Name", for: .normal)

    let Btn3 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 110, width: 100, height: 50))
    Btn3.setTitle("Btn3", for: .normal)
    Btn3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
    myStackView.addArrangedSubview(Btn3)
```

But Btn3 never appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming that your background color is default-white, the button is there, it's just hard to see ;). In other words: its title color is white.

Try setting some colors:

```
Btn3.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
Btn3.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
```

You could also create it as a system button if you care about `tintColor`:

```
let Btn3 = UIButton(type: .system)
```

If you create a button using `init(frame:)`, you get a custom button and [the `tintColor` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1624025-tintcolor) has this to say:

> This property has no default effect for buttons with type custom. For
>   custom buttons, you must implement any behavior related to tintColor
>   yourself.

Also, rather than specifying a meaningless frame (layout is managed by the stack view anyway) when initializing the button using `init(frame:)`, I'd suggest using `.zero`:

```
let Btn3 = UIButton(frame: .zero)
```

And a final note regarding Swift naming conventions:

> **Follow case conventions.** Names of types and protocols are
>   UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.

So `Btn3` suggests a type, while `btn3` or `loginButton` suggests a variable. See "[Follow case conventions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#follow-case-conventions)" in the Swift API Design Guidelines.

Comment: Definitely a stupid error ! And no problem with camel case of course, I messed up when typing the example code.

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself, I guess everybody has their fair share of "duh!" moments :). For cases like these I recommend Xcode's "Debug View Hierarchy" feature by the way. Also, please consider accepting this as the answer if it solved your problem.